# PHP preg_replace() problem

Tags: php, preg-replace

I was wondering if you could help.

I have the line:

```
$desc = preg_replace("/#\d{1,3}%/", "<b>$0</b>", $desc);
```

Where $desc is a tweet. Im hoping to recognise hash tags with a percentage. Such as:

```
#100% or #25% or #1%
```

However the string is not getting either matched or replaced. If you could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Example:

```
$desc = "testing #ugp 123 fb #75% #1% #100%. (Twitter@Feb 23, 2011 6:06 PM)";
$desc = preg_replace("/#\d{1,3}%/", "<b>$0</b>", $desc);
echo $desc;
```

Expected output would have the 3 matching tags to be wrapped in  tags, However output does not change from the original

Cheers

Comment: What is your expected output? This seems to be matching and wrapping `<b>` tags around the correct hash tags

Comment: Could you please provide an example of your input and the output you get (and the output you want)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

works for me:

```
$desc = "testing #ugp 123 fb #75% #1% #100%. (Twitter@Feb 23, 2011 6:06 PM)";
$desc = preg_replace("/#\d{1,3}%/", "<b>$0</b>", $desc);
echo $desc; //testing #ugp 123 fb <b>#75%</b> <b>#1%</b> <b>#100%</b>. (Twitter@Feb 23, 2011 6:06 PM)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

1. Place parentheses around the group you want to capture
2. Change $0 to $1 ($0 matches the entire regexp)

   `preg_replace("/#(\d{1,3}%)/", "<b>$1</b>", $desc);`

Comment: $0 matches the portion of the string that matched the expression, so with $0 it is bolding the hashtags...

Comment: yup, my answer was posted before he said exactly what he wanted, so i assumed he only wanted to extract and bold the \d{1,3}%